# Missing correct collision behaviour of objects, when using moveTo action

Tags: sprite-kit

i just started working with SpriteKit and encountered a problem:

I want to have an object, i call it playerController, that follows the players touch and a puck, with can be hit by the controller and will in that case bounce of the controller.

Somehow like an AirHockey game.

I constructed 2 SKNodes, with texture and physics, so they bounce of each other properly if gravity is on or if the controller is moving by some velocity.

BUT if the controller is moved by the following action the puck does not bounce of.

```
SKAction *moveTo = [SKAction moveTo: CGPointMake(touch.position.x ,touch.position.y) duration: 0.1];
[self.controllerPlayerOne runAction: moveTo];
```

Why? I already searched in the documentation and in several tutorials, but none addressed my problem. Maybe this is wanted by the SpriteKit developer, but how is in this case the realisation of following an touch?

Hopefully someone can help.

Edit:

Currently, i got the controller puck behaviour by setting the controllers position to the touch position and calculating the speed by using the last and the current position of the touch, each time the touch moved.

This is working pretty good.

Comment: Please add more relevant code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design. The same behavior can be observed in cocos2d btw.

The thing is: move actions move the sprite, not the physics body. Even if the physics body does follow the sprite, the move action overrules the physics body motion, at best putting it where the sprite is.

Instead when using physics bodies you must move them by changing the body's velocity, you can no longer reliably use the move actions. The physics body then moves the sprite.

Comment: One is actually able to retrieve contacts if using actions to move the body+sprite. But collisions which are *automatically* handled by the engine is another thing ;-).